# I'm designing a coroutine scheduler, what if the code in the coroutine calls a blocking syscall?

Tags: multithreading, compiler-construction, coroutine, goroutine

This is a scheduler similar to the one in Golang, implemented in C language, including GC (Garbage Collection). It will be used in the runtime of a programming language.

I am using musl libc. In Golang, hooks are inserted into all syscalls. Once a blocking system call is recognized, a new thread will be launched to execute the coroutine.

However, when my C code inevitably uses some external C libraries, if any of them have blocking system calls, it will block the entire thread, and the blocking time is unknown. I have some ideas now:

- Modify the musl libc code to inject hooks into all system calls, so I can know the current state of the thread?
- If the thread is blocked for a certain amount of time (e.g., 10ms), then I will start a new thread to handle the coroutine.
- Use thread_kill + sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART to forcibly gain control of the thread and proceed with subsequent recovery. The 'restart' here will restart the ongoing system call. I'm not sure how much this behavior will affect the blocking C libraries.

Are there other ways to determine if a thread is blocked by a system call? Or are there any better implementation ideas?

Comment: Can you explain why having a blocking system call is a problem?  e.g. why not just allow the thread to block until the system call returns, and then continue?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner In a coroutine system, there are usually only a small number of threads (generally chosen to be equal to the number of CPU cores). One thread will run tens of thousands of coroutines. If a single coroutine blocks the entire thread for a long time, then those tens of thousands of coroutines will not be scheduled. If I can quickly identify that this thread is blocked, then I can rapidly create another thread to take over those tens of thousands of coroutines.

Comment: You said, "...It will be used in the runtime of a programming language." You also said, "similar to...Golang." So, other than the fact that writing wrappers for every system call is tedious and repetitive work (Don't ask me how I know!) Why can't you do it the same way Golang does it? [P.S., Come to The Dark Side. We have code gen.]

Comment: @SolomonSlow When Golang calls C language code, it does not recognize what the C language is doing, but rather treats the entire C code block as a blocking system call. This results in the creation of a large number of operating system threads in CGO.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant Go does something you wanted to emulate rather than something you wished to avoid. Maybe look at Java's "project loom"/"virtual threads." In their nomenclature, a "virtual thread"/"fibre" must be "mounted" on a native "carrier" thread in order to run. IDK much about it, but it sounds like most of the standard library calls that block will "dismount" the caller from its carrier thread for the duration. (When dismount is not possible, they say that the virtual thread is "pinned" to its carrier.) Anyway, maybe you can find some inspiration in the OpenJDK source code.